# Надо подстроить бота под кнопки в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, telebot

Написал телеграмм бота. Друзья попросили сделать для него интерфейс. Целый день сижу фигачусь с этим проектом и не могу вдублить как подстроить так, чтобы chat_id был такой какой введет пользователь в интерфейсе. Извините за говнокод, я еще новичок

UPD: Добился того, что бот работает, но не отвечает на команды(ошибка не выходит)

```
import requests
import datetime
import cv2
import ctypes
import time
import pyautogui as pag
import platform as pf
import os
import telebot
from telebot import types
import webbrowser
from config import token, open_weather_token
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QProcess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
import sys

token = token

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
open_weather_token = open_weather_token

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = 'Злой бот'
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 250

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Sanserif', 12))
        self.lineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.onPressed)
        hbox.addWidget(self.lineedit)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText('Запустить')
        self.btn.move(20, 50)
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.start_bot)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText('Введи чат айди')
        self.label.move(50, 80)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Sanserif', 12))
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.show()

    def onPressed(self):
        self.chat = self.lineedit.text()
        requests.post(
            f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={self.chat}&text=Выбери команду: /ip, /spec, /screenshot,"
            f" /webcam, /message, /input, /wallpaper, /off, /sleep, /request, /website, /USD, /weather, /file, /folder")

    def start_bot(self):
        x = QProcess.run(['python', 'TheEvilBot.py'])


# Когда бот включен он пишет такое сообщение пользователю

# Функция при команде /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    rmk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btns = ['/ip', '/spec', '/screenshot', '/webcam',
            '/message', '/input', '/wallpaper', '/off', '/sleep', '/request', '/website',
            '/USD', '/weather', '/file', '/folder', ]  # Список с кнопками

    for btn in btns:  # Дабы не писать миллион строк кода проходимся циклом по массиву и добавляем каждую кнопку в список кнопок
        rmk.add(types.KeyboardButton(btn))

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите команду', reply_markup=rmk)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['folder'])
def choose_name(message):
    name_folder = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите название папки')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(name_folder, create_folder)


def create_folder(message):
    try:
        os.mkdir(rf'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\{message.text}')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Папка создана!')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['file'])
def get_folder(message):
    try:
        path = r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot'
        photos = []
        photos2 = []
        photos.append(os.listdir(path=path))
        for i in photos:
            for j in i:
                photos2.append(j)
        if '000.jpg' or 'cam.jpg' in photos2:
            photos2.remove('000.jpg') or photos2.remove('cam.jpg')
        else:
            pass
        mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пришлите название папки')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, rf'Вот все папки: {photos2}')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, get_name)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print('Я в get_folder')


def get_name(message):
    try:
        global name_f
        path = r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot'
        name_f = message.text
        if os.path.exists(rf'{path}\{message.text}'):
            pass
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Такой папки нет')
            return
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пришли фото, которое надо сохранить')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_photo)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print('Я в get_name')


def get_photo(message):
    file = message.photo[-1].file_id
    file = bot.get_file(file)
    dfile = bot.download_file(file.file_path)
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

    with open(rf'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\{name_f}\{timestr}' + '.jpg', 'wb') as timestr:
        timestr.write(dfile)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фото сохранено =)')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['ip', 'ip_address'])
def ip_address(message):
    response = requests.get(
        'http://jsonip.com/').json()  # Делаем запрос на сайт который показывает ip и парсив json формат
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Your ip address: {response["ip"]}')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['spec'])
def spec(message):
    msg = f'Name PC: {pf.node()}\nProcessor: i5 8300H, 4 cores, 2.4 GHz\nSystem: {pf.system()} {pf.release()}\nVideocard: Gtx GeForce 1060\nRAM: 8 Gb'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['screenshot'])
def screenshot(message):
    # Делаем скриншот и сохраняем в определенную директорию, дабы не засорять нынешнюю.
    pag.screenshot(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\000.jpg')

    with open(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\000.jpg', 'rb') as img:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['webcam'])
def webcam(message):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # Прогреваем камеру
    for i in range(30):
        cap.read()

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\cam.jpg', frame)
    cap.release()

    with open(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\cam.jpg', 'rb') as img:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['message'])
def message_sending(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите ваше сообщение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_message_sending)


def next_message_sending(message):
    try:
        pag.alert(message.text, '^')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что-то пошло не так')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['input'])
def message_sending_with_input(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите ваше сообщение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_message_sending_with_input)


def next_message_sending_with_input(message):
    try:
        # Чтобы бот не слетел делаем проверку try except
        answer = pag.prompt(message.text, '^')
        # Бот вызывает на компьютере команду которая подразумевает под собой ответ, собственно этот ответ мы и выводим
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что-то пошло не так')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['wallpaper'])
def wallpaper(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправьте картинку')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_wallpaper)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def next_wallpaper(message):
    try:
        file = message.photo[-1].file_id
        file = bot.get_file(file)
        dfile = bot.download_file(file.file_path)

        with open(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\image.jpg', 'wb') as img:
            img.write(dfile)

        path = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\image.jpg')
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Видимо, это не картинка')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['off'])
def off(message):
    # Кнопки с выбором (пользователь может случайно нажать на команду)
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no')
    # Добавляем кнопки в бота
    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выключить ноутбук?', reply_markup=markup_inline)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def calldata(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        # Если да, то выключаем
        os.system("shutdown /p")
        # Если нет, то ничего не делаем
    elif call.data == 'no':
        pass


@bot.message_handler(commands=['sleep'])
def sleep(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Переключаю ноутбук в режим сна')
    # Специальный файл для подобия сна у компьютера
    os.system("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['request'])
def get_request(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Какой запрос хотите сделать?')
    # Используем технологию next_step_handler
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_request)


def next_request(message):
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(f'{message.text}'))
    # Делаем гугл запрос с помощью библиотеки
    countdown(5)  # Ставим задержку перед отправкой чтобы страница успела прогрузиться
    pag.screenshot(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\000.jpg')

    # Отправляем файл
    with open(r'C:\Users\x1ag\Desktop\forbot\000.jpg', 'rb') as img:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['website'])
def get_website(message):
    # Мой сайт. Команда сделана лишь для кол-ва команд
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот ссылочка :)')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'https://x1ag.github.io/mywebsite1/')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['USD', 'usd'])
def get_data(message):
    req = requests.get('http://api.currencylayer.com/live?access_key=7fe2ed73dbae3284b2086b88a6a3d992')
    # Делаем API запрос на цену на все валюты
    response = req.json()
    sell_price = response['quotes']['USDRUB']  # Достаем оттуда цену
    sell_price = int(sell_price * 100) / 100  # Округляем до двух чисел после запятой
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     # Преобразуем дату для более удобного чтения
                     f'Сейчас {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y, %H:%M")}\nДоллар стоит: {sell_price}')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def get_weather(message):
    # Просим название города для дальнейшей обработки
    city = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пришлите название города")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(city, show_weather)


def show_weather(message):
    city = message.text
    code_to_smile = {
        'Clear': "Ясно \U00002600",
        'Clouds': 'Облачно \U00002601',
        'Rain': 'Дождь \U00002614',
        'Drizzle': "Дождь \U00002614",
        'Thunderstorm': 'Гроза \U000026A1',
        'Snow': 'Снег \U0001F328',
        'Mist': 'Туман \U0001F32B',
        # Смайлики для более приятного чтения
    }
    try:
        # Делаем исключения чтобы бот не слетел. Запрашиваем api с данными города
        r = requests.get(
            f'http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q={city}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric'
        )
        data = r.json()  # Преобразуем в json файл для более простого извлечения данных
        lat = data[0]['lat']
        lon = data[0]['lon']
        city = data[0]['name']
        # Получаем координаты города и его название

        # Делаем гет запрос чтобы получить файл со всеми погодными условиями в этом районе
        g = requests.get(
            f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={open_weather_token}'
            f'&units=metric')
        weather = g.json()

        weather_description = weather['weather'][0]['main']
        # Ищем названия чтобы поставить смайлики
        if weather_description in code_to_smile:
            wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
        else:
            wd = 'Посмотри в окно, я не понимаю что там за погода!'

        cur_weather = weather['main']['temp']  # Температура
        humidity = weather['main']['humidity']  # Влажность
        pressure = weather['main']['pressure']  # Давление
        wind_speed = weather['wind']['speed']  # Скорость ветра
        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(weather['sys']['sunrise'])  # Восход солнца
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(weather['sys']['sunset'])  # Закат солнца
        length_of_the_day = sunset_timestamp - sunrise_timestamp  # Продолжительность дня

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y, %H:%M")}***\n'
                                          f'Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n'
                                          f'Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind_speed}'
                                          f'м/c\n'
                                          f'Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\n'
                                          f'Продолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n'
                                          f'***Хорошего дня!***')

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Проверьте название города/штата')


# Счетчик секунд(для запроса в гугл)
def countdown(num_of_secs):
    while num_of_secs:
        m, s = divmod(num_of_secs, 60)
        min_sec_format = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(m, s)
        print(min_sec_format, end='/r')
        time.sleep(1)
        num_of_secs -= 1

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())


bot.polling()
```

Comment: попробуйте поместить ваш `requests.post` внутрь метода `onPressed`

Comment: @n1tr0xs помогло, но бот теперь сразу крашается когда запускаю

Comment: запустите его из консоли, чтобы увидеть ошибку из-за которой падает бот.

Comment: Я не могу проверить ваше приложение, но обратите внимание: 
1. `subprocess` - блокирует интерфейс. 
Попробуйте использовать `QProcess`, поскольку он запускает приложение, 
но не блокирует графический интерфейс, и выполняет аналогичную задачу, 
а также упрощает управление с помощью EventLop Qt. 
2. То что написано после `sys.exit(App.exec())`
(`bot.polling()`) - никогда не выполняется. 
3. Почему глобальные переменные - зло? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: @n1tr0xs ошибка вылезла - исправил. Теперь бот просто не отвечает на команды

Comment: @S.Nick 2. Тогда что и на что изменить? 3. Я понимаю, что глобальные переменные зло, но не придумал ничего лучше :(

Comment: Подскажите, как у Вас получилось добавить меню Телеграм-бота к PyQt? У меня просто при вызове функции с кодом Телеграм-бота - зависает программа и работа завершается. И куда бы я не пихал этот код - постоянно вылезает либо ошибка непонятная, либо не запускается что-то одно (окна из pyqt или сам телеграм-бот). Можно все же узнать, как стал выглядеть Ваш код после Ваших правок, где все заработало?

Answer (score 0):

Закинул весь код в функцию onPressed(за исключением трех строк(`App = QApplication(sys.argv) window = Window() sys.exit(App.exec())`))

И все сработало :)

ps. Правда закрывается неудобно и надо еще поработать над визуалкой, но под капотом все работает верно)